# ZXing in iOS: Counted.h not found error

Tags: ios, zxing

I have the same problem as other users.

In FormatReader.h:

```
#import <zxing/common/Counted.h>
```

It is happening when I try to use QRCodeReader, which extends FormatReader, where the problem happens.

I have made all the steps for integration and double checked them.

The project ZXingWidget is building ok, and it is using the same file.

I noticed that if I change the "<>" symbols to """ the problem disappears, but I am curios how to build without changing every single import in the library.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having this problem, I added the Header Search Paths in User Header Search Paths (did that before because of another issue) and now the problem was resolved when I changed Always Search User Paths to Yes.